# SQL Server & IIS Trusted Connection Conflict with AD Groups and Logins

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, iis-7

I have a weird situation.  I want to connect to SQL Server through a website using IiS7.  I also want a bunch of users to be able to connect to the database server through IIS via AD Group.

The issue is, I have to set Trusted_Connection=true in the web.config in order for SQLServer to know to use that users credentials as a windows account and not a sqlserver account.  If this is not set to true, all users in that AD group will try authenticating via sql accounts.

However when I do this, IIS uses the APPPool as the user to connect to the DB and then it doesn't matter the credentials the user use to log in.

I dont want to create an account per user.  That would defeat the purpose.

Please help, is there a workaround for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your IIS ASP application has to be configured to impersonate, see [Configure ASP.NET Impersonation Authentication (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730708%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). In addition you have to configure constrained delegation since you'll be doing a 'double hop'. See [How To: Use Protocol Transition and Constrained Delegation in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649317.aspx)

Comment: Will it allow me to allow IIS to use all those users?

Comment: Remus 0 know this is like 4 quick comments in a row, but the idea is so when i log in and exec sp_who2 i can see all the users via their real domain names, not just whatever account IIS is using

Comment: IIS 4.0? Do you mean Asp.Net 4.0? The instructions provided will work for any ASP.Net version 2.0 or higher.

Comment: Impersonation and delegation is the standard solution for your problem. The client credential (identity of user running the browser) flow all the way to the database SP, including all group membership. Read the links.

Comment: @RemusRusanu Let me ask you this, how would you do Forms Authentication ansd Asp.Net Impersation in IIS7.0

Comment: Forms implies *not* impersonation, that's pretty basic. Impersonation implies integrated authentication, never to be used with Forms.

Comment: @RemusRusanu Okay so in my scenario what am I looking for.  I have a bunch of outside users who I want to Auth in AD and login.  I want to be able to see them logged in and not the IIS app pool

Comment: @RemusRusanu if i leave just form auth on I get HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized

You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.

Comment: the bunch of users should first authenticate with Windows (eg. from the user login screen) and then open the browser that will properly authenticate them using the NTLM/Kerberos digest extensions. There is no 'outside' and 'AD', there is only AD.  You may have to set up a [VPN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/bb545442.aspx).

Comment: @RemusRusanu that wont work cant give all those guys a vpn, if I used Windows auth and there wasn't a user, how do you imp a login page without specifying an AD domain?

Comment: You don't. Either VPN, either not use AD, simple as that. Before anyone suggests passing the AD name/password over via Forms, two words: **don't**.

Comment: I think you've answered it i'm going to close this and redirect this to another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341180/iis-using-forms-authentication-to-create-ad-session-for-ad-auth