# IIS - using forms authentication to create AD session for AD auth

Tags: iis-7, active-directory

What i'm trying to do is have a forms authentication landing page where a user is presented a login.  The user then logs in and is redirected to another website where it's using AD authentication without requiring the user to login again.

Does anybody have an example?  Is this possible?

Comment: is the other website on another domain?

Comment: @user1012630 no it's all same domain, but i dont want the user typing in the domain name to login either

Answer (score 0):

Because you are on the same domain the other website should be able to read the cookie of the first website, and then ask website1 who is this user and website1 returns it is "ryan" 
then website2 authenticates the user as ryan.

this assumes that website2 trusts website1